# How we can find If application is running from Task manager through QTP but not from the "Processes" but from "Applications"

Tags: qtp

How we can find If application is running from Task manager through QTP but not from the "Processes"  but from "Applications"

Comment: You can get that information from `tasklist` dos command easily

Answer (score 0):

I tried with Desktop Objects. Hope you are trying to find the available window title. If that so, here is the method

'Negative Case

```
Msgbox IsProcessRunning("HP Unified",True)
'Positive Case
Msgbox IsProcessRunning("HPE Unified",True)
Public Function IsProcessRunning(ByVal Title,ByVal Contains)
    Dim blnIsRunning : blnIsRunning = False
    Set objDesc = Description.Create
    objDesc("micClass").Value = "Window"
    Set objCollection = Desktop.ChildObjects(objDesc)
    intWindowsCount = objCollection.Count - 1
    For intCount = 0 To intWindowsCount
        On Error Resume Next
        If IsObject(objCollection(intCount)) Then
            strWindowTitle = objCollection(intCount).GetROProperty("title")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If strWindowTitle <> "" Then
                If Contains And Instr(strWindowTitle,Title) > 0 Or Not Contains And Trim(Title) = Trim(strWindowTitle) Then
                    blnIsRunning = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If              
        End If
    Next
    IsProcessRunning = blnIsRunning
End Function
```